# Basic Method Calling - Max Integer

Tags: java

I have one public method and the method receives two numbers for example 2 and 7, how do I make it so that the method answers with the largest number i.e 7

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max(int x ,int y)  {
      int x = 2;
      int y = 7;
      return y > x; 
    }
  }
}
```

Is what i've gotten so far.

Comment: This is basically just asking us to write the code from scratch. Did you try absolutely anything?

Comment: please put some basic code you have tried

Comment: Where is you [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)?

Comment: Guys i'm an absolute beginner at this, i'm attempting this for the first time so please don't judge me harshly.

Comment: You can't define methods (directly) inside other methods. And you can't define variables with the same name as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's methods...

More practically: Java has a library called Math. Math has a static function that gives the max number between two numbers.

```
Math.max(firstNum, secondNum);
```

You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use if() statement to check if y is bigger than x. Return y if it is bigger. If not, return x.

And I have found a few errors in your code:

1.You need to state the access of method max(int x ,int y). In this case, public int max(int x, int y)

2. You should not define the variables x and y as int again (lines 4 and 5)
3. return y > x is returning type 'boolean', not 'int'.